# Can't make files or folders inside main Xcode project folder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create swift files and groups inside my main Xcode project group but for some reason it doesn't let me do it. When selecting new file it creates it outside of the group selected, and if I try and create a new group inside, the option is just greyed out.

I have never had this issue before with Xcode 11 and earlier, is this a feature that has been removed? Do I now have to make a separate group and work outside the initial project group?

Hopefully the image below will help explain what I mean.

**NOTE: I am running Xcode 12.2 on BigSur 11.0.1**

[image]

Here is what happens when I try to drag and drop the folder into the products group.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the second step of creating the file, do you still have selected the right folder?
Or is there maybe an other folder selected?

Comment: I have definitely selected the correct folder, I have tried numerous times in new projects to check and always get the same result.

Comment: But you can still drag & drop it into the right folder, or?

Comment: No I cannot drag and drop either. I have added a screen recording so you can see what happens.

Comment: My last idea is to try drag & drop the file into the right folder in the Mac Finder App. If this is not working for you to, I would advise you to reinstall Xcode.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that doesnt work! Looks like a reinstall for me!

Comment: I have reinstalled now and I can drag and drop in a new Xcode project but not in my current one. Is there a good way to copy all the swift files across to a new project instead of one by one? I dont want to start again.

Comment: maybe try to duplicate, I am not sure if the settings of this project are copied too. Just give it a try

Answer (score 2):

I also created an iOS App titled "Products". Upon changing the name to something else (Product Manager) I was able to add files to the project

Comment: You're correct. I just tested this in Xcode 12.4 and the same thing happened. "Products" is a non-folder group auto-generated by Xcode within a project file where you see your build products listed (.app bundle, test targets, appex plugins etc.) and this conflict confuses Xcode. Even if you try to rename Xcode's auto-generated "Products" group name to something else, Xcode still won't let you add files to the "Products" app source files folder in OP's post.